# In Swift, how do you remove background from a video?

Tags: swift, avmutablecomposition, avmutablevideocomposition

I'm playing with SwiftUI and have an intro video playing, but wondering how I can remove the background of a video so it will appear transparent

If I replace the AVPlayerItem it does display and plays (with a black background)
If I attempt to add the videoComposition (even with no instructions) it doesn't display anything other than a black box.

I'm not sure if my CGSize is correct, or the CMTime is correct.

Here is the code:

```
import AVKit
import SwiftUI

struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    @State var player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyVideo", withExtension: "mov")!))
    
    init() {
        removeBackgroundFromVideo()
    }
    
    func removeBackgroundFromVideo() {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyVideo", withExtension: "mov")!)
        let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        instruction.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTime(seconds:0,preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(1)), duration: CMTime(seconds:8,preferredTimescale:CMTimeScale(1)))
        videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]
        videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width:1000,height:1000)
        videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(seconds: 8, preferredTimescale: 1)
        //item.videoComposition = videoComposition
        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
        //player.currentItem?.videoComposition = videoComposition
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
                .frame(width: 500,height: 500)
                .onAppear {
                    player.play()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Swift, you can use the AVFoundation framework to work with videos.
Removing the background from a video involves a more complex process,
often requiring computer vision and machine learning techniques.
If you have a pre-trained model for background removal,
you can integrate it into your Swift application.  to more shorts

```
import AVFoundation
guard let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "your_video", withExtension: "mp4") else {
    return
}

let asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first
```

Create an AVMutableComposition to work with the video.

```
let composition = AVMutableComposition()
let videoCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

guard let exportURL = // URL for the exported video file else { return }

let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
exportSession?.outputURL = exportURL
exportSession?.outputFileType = .mp4

exportSession?.exportAsynchronously {
    if exportSession?.status == .completed {
        // Handle successful export
    } else if let error = exportSession?.error {
        // Handle export error
        print("Export failed with error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: you've got some formatting problems with your answer. The first part appears to be the middle of a function (`guard let` statements have to be in the body of a function so there is something to return from.) Further, some of your code isn't indented at all, so it doesn't get code formatting. You might want to enclose the whole block of code in triple tick marks (```) so it gets code-formatted regardless of indentation.

Comment: The video has an alpha channel (which isn't supported from what I have found) but if I can change the backgroundColor to clear, then the video should play on a transparent background.

Comment: What does the code in this answer have to do with removing the video's background? What does the first set of code have to do with the second set of code?